# Formatting a csv file by deleting and transforming columns with Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv, format

I want to modify a data frame in python with the pandas function. So I want to delete the first and the 7th column `(Unix Timestamp, Close)`. I have also moved the column `Symbol` to the end of the columns. How could I do these transformations to the csv file below. I want the formats to be written in the csv file permanently, would this be possible?

```
import pandas as pd
url= input.csv
data = pd.read_csv(url, low_memory=False)
```

original csv:

[image]

Formatted csv/Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: Although you've got an answer, you should post the `original csv` as formatted text, so that other users can reproduce it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly drop your columns by `drop()` method:-

```
data=data.drop(columns=['Unix Timestamp','Close'])
```

Now use `pop()` method:-

```
symbol=data.pop('Symbol')
```

Finally:-

```
data['Symbol']=symbol
```

After that if you wants to change the contents of csv file then save this data to your csv file by `to_csv()` method

```
data.to_csv(url)
```

**Note:-** If you don't want to save index then pass `index=False` in `to_csv()` method

Comment: Ty for the code, but I am trying to permanently format the contents of the csv file. Is there anyway I could do that?